# How did forces get into the Webway to fight the Demon incursion during the Horus Heresy

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

After Magnus broke through the Webway and destroyed the Golden Throne in his attempt to warn the Emperor a war started to prevent demons from flooding through into Earth. In several short stories and descriptions of this part of the Palace a large pair of doors are described, the size of a Titan in front of which stand Custodes and Sisters of Silence in armor that looks like it has been in some great battle, and behind the doorway can be heard a great war taking place.

In addition there are other sources that describe someone seeing injured centurions as if they have fought in a great war.

Has it ever been described how these Loyalist soldiers were transported to and from the battle front, were the giant doors opened to allow forces in and out or did they get there some other means (teleport etc) or did the forces, once inside the battle, never get out?

Comment: Do you mean loyal or traitor forces? Both?

Comment: Apologies question updated, Loyal, the Traitor I know got in through the breach Magnus had created direct from the warp.

Comment: No apologies needed! Short answer through the imperial dungeon, longer answer - read the Master of Mankind. Proper answer will come later!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TLDR**

Through the Imperial Dungeon.

**Longer Version**

Most of this is explained in The Master of Mankind. In it several of the characters are led down into the webway from the surface. The journey starts in The Emperor's palace and they're led through the dungeon, into the laboratory, and then emerge in the webway (although the distinction is not as clear as that).

From the descriptions in the book it sounds as though it's a long, long way down and is decorated with murals depicting the unification wars, the great crusade, and the discovery of the webway.

There are several features described on the way down. One is the lost city of Kathmandu (now deep underground), another is The Golden Throne which sits facing the entrance to the webway.

It's described how the way down is big enough for most titans/tanks to make their way down. However the largest titans need to be dissembled and rebuilt inside the larger tunnels.

Ultimatly we see this confirmed when the warlord titan The Scion of Vigilant Light

> who remains behind to cover the exit as the defenders retreat towards the throne room.

This was because she couldn't fit back down the corridors.

Comment: I should add - the book is well worth the read, probably the best of the HH I've read!

Comment: Ok cool thanks, will add that to the list, stopped reading them after the Pythos one there seemed a series of bad books that put me off, so they never use the giant titan size doors then in the book? Seems pointless having them there then :).

Comment: They do use them, and they're big enough to let smaller titans through - but they're too small for the BIG titans

Comment: Ok have more questions but have ordered the book so will wait to read that first :)

Comment: @RichardC, it's a good book - but it'll make you want to start collecting titans and custodes!

Comment: If I was going to have a 40K army it would be Titans and Custodes already :)